# How to pixelated an image?

Tags: python, android, ios, image, pixel

[image]

As you can see the pic above, I want to implement a function in mobile application: User select a picture or take photo. Then I can pixelated this picture.
I find a python model to implement this function. But my server performance is not high, it takes almost 10 seconds to  process image. And I find that the price of server with GPU is very high, I can't afford it.
My question is : Is there any free or paid API to implement this function, or recommend cheap price server with GPU. Or any other approaches to achive this goal.Thank you.

Comment: Why not do it in the device itself? It’s a simple things to do and 10 seconds sounds like there’s something wrong.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen what you mean is to deploy the model in the phone device? how about the process speed?

Comment: If a simple pixelation needs “a model” it really feels over engineered. This could be done in milliseconds on computers 20 years ago so it shouldn’t take 10 seconds on a modern one.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen it is not simple mosaic. it is artistic pixelation.

Comment: For this question to be answerable, you have to give more details about exactly what you are trying to do. And even then, it sounds like it would fall under the "asking for recommendations about external resources" guidelime.